# Problems with converting some text in Tkinter Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a program which works well in console but then i tried to use this program with tkinter. The program is still working but the converted text is not the text that written in the Entry class of tkinter. The codes are below:

```
from tkinter import *

def dictionary():
    ascii_dictionary = {chr(i): bin(i)[2:] for i in range(128)}
    for i in ascii_dictionary:
        if len(ascii_dictionary[i]) < 8:
            count = 8 - len(ascii_dictionary[i])
            ascii_dictionary[i] = "".zfill(count) + ascii_dictionary[i]
    non_ascii_dictionary = {chr(i): bin(int(bytes(chr(i).encode(encoding="utf-8")).hex(), 16))[2:10] + " " +
                        bin(int(bytes(chr(i).encode(encoding="utf-8")).hex(), 16))[10:18] for i in range(128, 512)}
    dictionary = ascii_dictionary.copy()
    dictionary.update(non_ascii_dictionary)
    return dictionary

class Application():

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.frame_1 = Frame()
        self.frame_1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.widgets()
        self.mainloop = self.window.mainloop()

    def widgets(self):

        self.label_1 = Label(self.frame_1,text="Text To Binary:")
        self.label_1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.entry_1 = Entry(self.frame_1)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.button_1 = Button(self.frame_1,text="Convert",command=self.convert)
        self.button_1.grid(row=0,column=2)

    def convert(self):
        text_1=str(self.entry_1)
        return_value = dictionary()
        list_1 = [return_value[j] for i in text_1 for j in return_value if i == j]
        text_2 = " ".join(list_1)
        print(text_1,text_2)

instance=Application()
```

For example when i type "hello" to the Entry then press the convert button, i see that the converted word is ".6138064.9675856". In your opinion, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
text_1=str(self.entry_1)
```

`str(self.entry_1)` gets the string representation of the `entry_1` widget. The string representation of a widget is its unique identifier, a collection of decimal points and digits. If you want the text inside the entry, use `get`.

```
text_1=str(self.entry_1.get())
```